# Windows Advanced Firewall (Command Line Interface)

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-firewall

I'm wondering where to find detailed information regarding the Microsoft Advanced Windows Firewall command line settings. For instance, from reading a couple technet articles I've learned that I can run the following:

```
netsh advfirewall firewall set rule group=”File and Printer Sharing” new enable=Yes
```

The bit about 'group="File and Printer Sharing"' is the part I'm having trouble finding documentation for.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. And, if possible, I'd rather a pointer to the docs than a simple listing of group names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After digging further I believe that I have found the answer I was looking for. A printout of all currently set rules and their corresponding groups may be viewed by issuing the following:

```
netsh advfirewall firewall show rule name=all
```

For further reference, the documentation summary printout may be viewed by issuing the following:

```
netsh advfirewall firewall show rule /?
```